# Azure blob image not loading in browser

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We upload some customers files to an azure storage account and then allow access to them from web app.

I have a problem with some files over 1 Mb as webbrowsers display them as a blank square but they are correctly uploaded and can be downloaded to.

What really puzzles me is that the response headers are all ok but the image is not displayed.

Example response headers:

- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- Content-Length: 1615694
- Content-Type: image/jpeg
- Content-MD5: A9QHxxvIeNq42 b/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
- x-ms-request-id: bc828201-c01e-002d-488c-a57150000000
- x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
- x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
- x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
- Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-ms-request-id,Server,x-ms-version,Content-Type,Last-Modified,ETag,Content-MD5,x-ms-lease-status,x-ms-blob-type,Content-Length,Date,Transfer-Encoding
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
- Date: Mon, 01 Aug 2022 09:54:56 GMT

Comment: Have you tried downloading the file from Azure blob and opening it locally? Maybe during the upload process file gets corrupted. Or try to compare the files - the one you're uploading and the one you download from blob.

Comment: "... but they are correctly uploaded and can be downloaded to."
I don't have the original file as they are uploaded by customers but if I download them and reupload happens to.

Comment: What I meant is that when you download the file you can open it locally? So, you can make sure its not corrupted?

Comment: Yes. Also edited the image to halve its size from 1.5 mb to around 600 kb and then upload the smaller one. And it loads ok on browser.

Comment: Would you be able to share a link to the file on this storage account? And if possible source code where you upload the file. It would be much easier to debug.

Comment: Since the files are uploaded by your customer and your own uploaded files work fine: My guess is that the file is corrupt in a way that the browser refuses to display it. Maybe it is not really a JPEG? Try analyzing the files for errors.

Comment: Customer files are OK. It seems is something about how files are served from azure storage accounts but I can't find exactly WHY or where to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

•   Please ensure that the **below HTTP parameters in the header are set as below** accordingly such that the images are displayed correctly and not like squares depicting them: -

```
 Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy : *
 Content-Security-Policy : CSP Level 3
```

Also, do **ensure that the browser versions are up-to date** and the setting **‘Block third party cookies’ is disabled**. You will have to go to **‘Settings --> Privacy and Security --> Site settings --> Cookies and site data --> Set ‘Block third party cookies to OFF’'**

•   Do also ensure that you are **disabling the ‘Flash and Ads Blocker extension’ such that the images content from other unauthenticated and unvalidated origins is also allowed**. Finally, also please **ensure that the browser that you are using is up to date with necessary security updates** such that the **‘Content Security Policy’ is supported by them for reducing the attack surface of CSS (Cross-Site-Scripting) attacks**.

Please refer the below link for more details: -

**[https://content-security-policy.com/#:~:text=The%20Content-Security-Policy%20header,is%20often%20abbreviated%20as%20CSP%20.](https://content-security-policy.com/#:%7E:text=The%20Content-Security-Policy%20header,is%20often%20abbreviated%20as%20CSP%20.)**

**https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers/**

Comment: The image doesn't load on any site. It happens if you open its url on a browser.

Comment: That's what I am trying to say that please check the browser settings as specified. It would be of help.

Comment: Block third party cookies  OFF check
No Flash or adblocker extensions check
Browser updated check
Headers not present and seems that can't be added without creating a cdn or proxy site that adds them.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that comes to my mind is that the content type is not being set when creating the blob. Take a look if your code looks like the following;

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("YOURCONNECTIONSTRING");
var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("YOURCONTAINERNAME");
var blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient("YOURFILE.jpg");

var blobHttpHeader = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpeg" };
 
var uploadedBlob = await blob.UploadAsync(YOURSTREAM, new BlobUploadOptions { HttpHeaders = blobHttpHeader });
```

PS: the last two lines